# Spanish accent in BundleDisplayName

Tags: special-characters, non-ascii-characters, cfbundledisplayname

I need add an spanish accent in the Bundle Display Name but I get this result in screenshot above in devices and simulator.

The problem is the accent was moved over the wrong letter (the word must be show "Caligrafía" not the accent over the "f" as appear)

Does exist any way to fix this?

Any help will be appreciated. I'm using Xcode 5.1 and iOS 7.1

[image: Screenshot with Bundle Name with Accent (special character in spanish)]

Also add a screenshot from my info.plist

[image]

*** UPDATE *** (Apr-30-2014)
I receipt info from apple and apparently they recognize it as a bug. They give me this bug number 16379794. I will refresh this case when receive any information from them.

Comment: It seems a typo in your config file, Info.plist I guess...

Comment: @Roberto_Sanchez I wrote Caligrafía in my info.plist in "Bundle Display Name Field", but if you check slowly, you can saw the accent over the letter "f" and is no way posible to do that (in spanish). The consonant can't have accent just vowels. So i don't know why the accent moves in icon's name.

Comment: Wow, what a weird case!, It seems a iOS issue, what iOS versions have you tested ?

Comment: I used Xcode 5.1 and iOS 7.1 in a new project.

Comment: I have same problem
<img src="https://www.evernote.com/shard/s32/sh/d88c45b1-dd3e-4cb3-9631-f08d0747a95a/30394d4e52a579b361182ff3eb0da458/deep/0/iOS-Simulator---iPhone-Retina-(4-inch)---iOS-7.1-(11D167).png">

Comment: @PedroBrasileiro I guess is a Bug, as a temp solution, i will write CaligrafÍa (capital Í) to fix, but i don´t like it.

Comment: I receipt info from apple and apparently they recognize it as a bug. They give me this bug number 16379794. I will refresh this case when receive any information from them.

Comment: I have the same problem. I have submitted a bug report to Apple. BTW, it worked fine on iOS 4 to 6.

Comment: Thanks, @MariánČerný I hope in 8.0 will fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem of iOS 7. It worked fine on iOS 4 to 6. It has been fixed in iOS 8 (verified on iOS 8 beta, seed 2).

Comment: Thanks. I'll check and select this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce the issue easily:

[image]

It seems a bug related with representation of character "í" in the app display name (CFBundleDisplayName), I suggest to open a bug in https://bugreport.apple.com/

Depending on how you combine the character "í", the result is different, as you can see in screenshot, even if you put 2 "íí" the second one disappears.

I'm sorry I can not help you too much, but I wanted to confirm that this is not an isolated case.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I imagined that. Let me try to open a bug report in Apple. If i don´t receive any other answer i will check your answer as a valid.

Comment: I open bug report in Apple. I will update according Apple's answer.